# Book where a woman from an all-female planet falls to another planet

Tags: story-identification, books

This book has a planet with all females. The planet is linked to another world.

The protagonist falls to that planet and is found by a brother and sister. I think the sister could understand her or she could understand the sister. I remember them locking her up up in a cage with other magical creatures like a tree which she can talk to.

I also think the high priest of the other planet has some plot to keep in power. The brother and sister free her and they go on a journey.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?  How did she fall, did she fall in a hole, start a drifting upwards, or what?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: If I remember correctly she was sacrificed by the head priestess by tossing her from their world (which is connected somehow to the other) to the other. I also remember the father of the kids showing her blood was magical. Think the son was cut or something and they used her blood to heal him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok thank you both for the help. You helped me approach the questioning in a different way and I found the book. blood was the key as well as the priestess sacrificing her.

*[The Cerulean](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/amy-ewing/the-cerulean/)* by Amy Ewing.

> An exploration of feminine power, autonomy, and sexuality.
>
> Nearly 18, Sera has led a protected life in the City Above the Sky, an all-female society connected to a planet via a magic tether. Her race of Ceruleans possess blue hair, blood, and eyes and silvery skin. Sera is chosen to sacrifice herself by jumping off the edge of the City to break the tether so that her people can locate another planet with resources to draw upon. On the planet below, 18-year-old biracial human twins navigate another culture’s social restrictions. Leo, who appreciates women and fashion, takes after their Pelagan mother with his blue eyes and light skin, while Agnes, who is attracted to women (in a homophobic culture) and loves science, resembles their Kaolin father with her brown skin and eyes. The two go on an expedition to collect another specimen for their ruthless father’s popular theatrical freak shows and come across Sera, who never could muster the romantic feelings for girls her society expected, following her crash. Most citizens of Kaolin are brown-skinned, while the Pelagans are predominantly fair-skinned. In places, the text appears to unquestioningly privilege lighter complexions. In alternating narration, Ewing (The Black Key, 2016, etc.) provides intricate, well-explained worldbuilding, slowly unveiling a deeply buried mystery and leaving characters poised for new discoveries.

Comment: It's perfectly valid to answer your own question, but you are still expected to make a good answer that explains why it matches. You will be able to click on the checkmark by the voting buttons to accept in about 48 hours (it's the rule for self-answers).

Comment: It's great that you figured it out.  Please come back on Friday so you can accept your answer.  It might also be worth adding a bit more detail here, maybe quoting the plot summary, so at least we have the names of major characters and the like.  (That will make this answer more useful to the next person looking for this book.)

Comment: I went ahead and added some details, but you can [edit] more in.